# Maintain Environmental Variables Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel, jenkins, laravel-5

Might looks like a basic stuff, but I am confused.

How can I maintain the environmental variables(.env) in Laravel or any environment. ?

For example, DB credentials might varies for different environment.

As of now, all the deployment process are progressing in Jenkins or any deployment tools, it would be good to automate the process
of moving the environmental variables to the specific server.

I think, In earlier days, env variables are modified directly in the server by getting into the SSH or any Connection type.
It would create many confusion on many situations.
Here are my questions,

1. How can we maintain the environmental variables ? (May be git or any versioning system)
2. How can we move the environmental file from Jenkins server to Application server ?
3. How could docker like tools will be helpful here ?

Comment: Not sure the best answer but I keep these in a config file which usually you do not store in a git repo. One for local, dev (etc.) and prod. It works because your prod config file can turn off error displays, where logging happens and db, api, etc. credentials.

Comment: I wouldn't keep database credentials under version control. These could be saved into your .env file the first time you run your Laravel site, and then left there. Other non-sensitive properties that must be under version control could then be saved into a different file. There are many automated deployment systems for PHP that will either leave your defined configuration files untouched or write config files during deployment, I can't speak for Jenkins but [Deployer](https://github.com/REBELinBLUE/deployer) will do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would not recommend storing sensitive information in a VCS.
2. Your application we still need a .env file on whatever machine
   it's running, whether that be a development, build, or production
   server.
3. Docker and related CI tools are very useful in that they help
   maintain a consistent release flow and provide automated testing and
   deployment, just to name a couple benefits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jenkins I would recommend writing the env file during the actual build. Jenkins will then zip the contents of the project and send those to whatever environment you have set up. The plugin can be found here
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text+File+Operations+Plugin This will allow you to keep the env file up to date with any changes during your development process. If you are deploying to lets say Elastic Beanstalk there is an area of the site where you can add server variables to the EBS instance. The variables are under Configuration → Software Configuration:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1iAv.png]

Comment: Yep! It would be good. Any other options to maintain that changes that would happen simillar like git ?

Comment: You won't be able to store this file on git. Reason being there is sensitive information within this file that someone with malicious intent would love to get their hands on.